# Inno Setup: Shutdown service for custom page

Tags: inno-setup

I'm building an installer using Inno Setup where I need to convert some existing files if the application is already installed.

To do so I need to stop the applications service which works automatically for the install process. Is there a way to hook a page between the application shutdown and start routine? Or to postpone the application restart to a later time?

EDIT:
I also tried CheckForMutexes('MyAppMutex') to manually prompt the user to close the application, but the function always returns false.

EDIT2:
My current workarround uses the [isProcessRunning script by jakoch](https://github.com/WPN-XM/WPN-XM/blob/master/bin/innosetup-scripts/isProcessRunning.iss) to prompt the user to manually close the application. I would prefer a more automatic solution though.

Comment: What does it mean *"hook a page between the application shutdown and start routine"*? Can you elaborate?